error when connecting gdb with gdb server
Environment: WSL2 Ubuntu 22.02
My project runs in the Docker container from the WSL2.
The scheduler in my project is responsible for starting all the applications.
gdbserver is started from the scheduler with the below args:
<ipaddress>:1234 <binary>
And from the WSL2, I try to connect to the gdbserver and face the below error:
(gdb) target remote <ipaddress>:1234
Remote debugging using <ipaddress>:1234
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
warning: unrecognized item "timeout" in "qSupported" response
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Remote replied unexpectedly to 'vMustReplyEmpty': timeout

Note: Both gdb and gdbserver are using same version (12.1)
I tried passing --no-startup-with-shell to the gdbserver. It didnt worked.
I also tried increasing the remotetimeout on the target side which as well didn't worked
set remotetimeout 200
